Get the number of elements of the longest continuous sequence in Google Earth Engine
I have a List/Array
[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]

and I want to get the number of elements in a sequence of consecutive ones. It should be easy to implement using ordinary JavaScript, but I don't know why the following code doesn't work. Actually, I understand that .map() in Google Earth Engine, but I really can't implement it on my own, forgive me for asking a beginner's question.
Anyone have any suggestions?
Here is my original idea:
var array_diffList = ee.List([1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]);

function longestNonZeroSequenceLength(arr) {
  
    var max_length = 0;  
    var curr_length = 0;  
    var length = arr.length().getInfo();

    for (var i=0; i < length; i++) {
      
        if (arr.get([i]) !== 0) { 
          
          currentLength += 1; 

          maxLength = ee.Algorithms.If(currentLength > maxLength, currentLength, maxLength)
          // var max = ee.Number(maxLength).max(curr);  
        } else {
          
          currentLength = 0;  
          
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}

var result = longestNonZeroSequenceLength(ee.Array(array_diffList));

The ultimate goal is to get the number 5
https://code.earthengine.google.com/92ebfedc37ac9ec7aa18c9b52798abcc

https://medium.com/google-earth/runs-with-arrays-400de937510a
